# Need custom configuration parameter value for Xamarin App (Intune Azure)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, intune

**More Info: In Azure, the policy appears to be as this:**

## State: succeeded

.....................................................

We are implementing a Mobile device management (MDM) Intune solution on our company. Following the guide steps, we uploaded our iOS line-of-business app to the platform, and assigned it an App Configuration policy.

What we want to achieve, is to retrieve a custom config parameter value, from our MDM app config file into the Xamarin App.

There is a XML property list that contains the **app configuration settings** for devices **enrolled** in Intune. 
When you create an **app configuration file**, you can specify one or more of the following values by using below format

```
<dict>

  <key>keyone</key>

  <string>valuekeyone</string>

  <key>keytwo</key>

  <string>valuekeytwo</string>

</dict>
```

In my case, I am using **2** different keys and values.

**keyone --> valuekeyone**

**keytwo --> valuekeytwo**

I have followed the following documentation, but there is no way to retrieve these fields from the **Xamarin.iOS** app code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-configuration-policies-use-ios#enter-xml-data

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

After some R&D, There are some Methods in the API which output the expected values:

```html
IntuneMAMPolicyManager value = IntuneMAMPolicyManager.Instance;
NSDictionary dictionary =  value.DiagnosticInformation;

NSString[] keys = new NSString[]
{
    new NSString("AppConfig")

};

NSDictionary key= dictionary.GetDictionaryOfValuesFromKeys(keys);


var field1 = new NSObject();
var field2 = new NSObject();


for (int i = 0, keyCount = (int)key.Count; i < keyCount; i++)
{
    var author = key.ElementAt(i);
    NSObject fields_values = author.Value;
    field1 =  fields_values.ValueForKey(new NSString("field1"));
    field2 =  fields_values.ValueForKey(new NSString("field2"));
    Console.WriteLine("field1: {0}, field2: {1}", field1.ToString(), field2.ToString());
   
}
```

Now, It works :)